# How can I make a Power switch switch on when the device is powered up?

Tags: tasmota

I have a ceiling light attached to a Tasmota-flashed Shelly and want it to be on whenever the device gets power (again). Much like Hue bulbs can be defined to wake up lit up. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Tasmota [Rules](https://tasmota.github.io/docs/Rules) are your friend. To achieve the desired outcome, put

```
Rule1 ON Power1#boot DO POWER1 1 ENDON
Rule1 1
```

in the Console. `Rule1 1` activates the respective rule. Also make sure that POWER1 is the right switch altogether.